# How to set a maximum width and height for leaflet tootips

Tags: leaflet, tooltip

I have an website where a user can set a tooltip content (free text input).

Since HTML can be used in leaflet tooltip content, such HTML can be set as the tooltip content :

`var html = '<img src="https://www.somesite.com/someimage.jpg">';
marker.bindTooltip(html);`

If the image is very large, the tooltip display is as large as the image, potentially larger than the window..

I would like to set a maximum width and height of the tooltip. Such properties exist for popups (maxWidth, maxHeight options), but not for tootips.

I tried adding these to the tooltip CSS definition, but it does not do anything:

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
    max-width: 128px;
    max-height: 128px;
}
```

Any simple way to do this ?
Thank you

Comment: welcome! can you provide a reproducible example? (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here a reproducible example:

https://jsfiddle.net/antoineschmitt/r6xkLb9t/14/

(sorry for the cat picture) In this example, the srcImg content is actually not controlled by me, it comes from a user interface, users can input any text, including html. When such html refers to an image, this image can be too large. I'd like to set a maximum width and height to whatever content the tooltip has.

Comment: have you tried a more specific CSS selector? `.leaflet-tooltip` might not be enough, what about something like `.someContainer .someClass .leaflet-tooltip img` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add an 'id' or 'class' to the image and set the max-height and max-width to it.

js

```
var html = '<img id="image" src="https://www.somesite.com/someimage.jpg">';
marker.bindTooltip(html);
```

css

```
#image {
  max-width: 128px;
  max-height: 128px;
}
```

See my Codepen for an example: https://codepen.io/amapolauditiva/pen/bGVpWdQ

> Answer extended

Also you can fit all the images that are inside of the tooltip:

```
.leaflet-tooltip img {
  max-width: 128px;
  max-height: 128px;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but as I explain in the comment to my original post, I have no control over the content of the text that is attached to the tooltip. I could of course parse it, and if it is an img, add a class to it and do as you suggest. I would prefer to have a simpler way.